# How to pass the "#" character as a parameter from URL using AJAX in MVC

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I have a below request 
http://localhost:16770/Admin/Category/GetColorByCode/#00aabb

As this request contain the # and the controller method is not been called in asp.net core mvc.

Here is the ajax code

```
var ajaxUrl = ApplicationRootUrl("GetColorByCode", "Category") + "/" + self.colorCode();
$.ajax({
         type: "GET",
         contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
         url: ajaxUrl,
         dataType: "json",
         success: function (data) {
           if (data.isSuccess) {

           } else {
                self.Error(true);
                self.message(data.successMessage);
           }

           $('#LoadingImage').hide();
         },
         error: function (err) {

         }

});
```

Server side code

```
[HttpGet("colorCode")]
public JsonResult GetColorByCode(string colorCode)
{ 
}
```

The controller method is not been called as the query string contain #. I know this is because of the #. I want to pass with the #. How can, I achieved this in asp.net core using ajax called.

Comment: [Percent encoding.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) Replace the hash with %23.

Comment: That's the only solution? How can I send directly

Comment: You can pass as a data parameter in ajax `var daata = {'colorCode':'#abc'}` and than stringify to json `JSON.stringify(daata)` and than pass as a data parameter in ajax `data:JSON.stringify(daata),` or you can make your ajax request as a `POST` as well as if you wants to find what's difference between `get` and `post` find [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/key-differences-post/)

Comment: @SanJaisy You can use encodeURIComponent() function in jquery and decode it with Server.UrlDecode() in controller side

Comment: @SanJaisy did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have added NetFiddle. It works [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/qqTTUz)

You can use `Url.Action()` with javascript `encodeURIComponent()` function then decode the `"#value"` with `Server.UrlDecode()` function in controller side like following.

**//jquery**

```
var ajaxUrl = '@Url.Action("GetColorByCode", "Home")' + '?value='  + encodeURIComponent('#value');
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: ajaxUrl,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
        console.log(result);
        if (result.isSuccess) {
            alert(result.data)
        } else {
            self.Error(true);
            self.message(data.successMessage);
        }

                    $('#LoadingImage').hide();
        },
        error: function (err) {

        }                   
});
```

**//controller**

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetColorByCode(string value)
{       
    var resultValue = Server.UrlDecode(value);
    return Json(new { data = resultValue, isSuccess = true}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);                         
}
```